# striping the (,u'',) and \n from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, selenium, split

I cannot get rid of the \n, and I am writing too much syntax since there is probably an easy way to do it, or even better, a way not to lift it from the page to begin with. Here is the code, and below is where it comes from using python 2.7 selenium(webdriver) chromedriver

```
"Mileage" : str(str(mileage).strip("(u'',)")).strip("\n"),
    "MPG_Range" : str(mpg).strip("(u'',)"),
```

OUTPUT : 7,145 miles\n   ,   24/31\n

They come from a page scrape:

```
    mileage = car.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'Mileage:')]/following-sibling::dd").text,

    mpg = car.find_element_by_xpath(".//dt[contains(text(),'MPG Range:')]/following-sibling::dd").text,
```

I guess it would be a great time to also learn how to get rid of the miles\n or just \n. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use replace function after strip

Comment: The "u" in `u"some string"` just signifies it is a unicode string, it's not actually contained in the string. The `'\n'` Is a newline. Do you actually want to remove newlines? I think you are conflating the string with the *representation* of the string.

Comment: @juanpa I am saving it to the database from the dictionary, it saves with the (,u' ',) and                                                                                                         "HB Man Pzev" "I-5 cyl" "Manual" "$10,979" "Black" "Titan Black" "CPO" "H0451A" "23/33\n" "n/a" Thas copied from the DB browser

Comment: I think since I am scraping the element I am getting the \n attached to the string.

Comment: str(mpg).strip() should work, no need to add any parameter